# Can I override a module's A method on a module B?

Tags: java, spring

I have the module A which is a dependency for many other modules. It cannot be changed at anyway. In this module the method `getCellValue()` is declared. Module A is a dependency for module B. The latter module is changeable. Important note is that the aforementioned method is not being called from module B.

Below is my question:
Can I override `getCellValue()` method in module B?

Tech Stack: Spring 4.1.6 - Java 8.

Comment: do you know what 'override' means?

Comment: As long as the `getCellValue()` method is not private, you can overwrite it in module B. But the overwritten version will only be used, where an instance of B is in use. All occurances, where A is in use, the method of A will be used.

Comment: You can, as long as `B` extends `A` and `getCellValue` is not `final`. Did you try it?

Comment: Can you defined _is a dependency for_, not sure of the orientation of the relation.

Comment: Imho module is some kind of ambiguous noun for class, which you meant in this case, right? So why not name A and B as classes?
When I read module, I first thought of the deprecated project [spring-modules](http://forum.spring.io/forum/attic/spring-modules) :)

Comment: @DavidArtmann I assume a module is a (maven?) module, so not a specific class. bit vague as description

Comment: Yes it is a maven module. I described it so generally because it is actually not a coding problem.

Comment: @Stultuske yes, you may be right. The author updated the question. Now it's more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the class enclosing the method is not `final` you can extend it and `@Override` the method. Inject the extended class in all places where the original class is injected and your overridden behavior will be called.

Comment: This is generally working, but the issue is that the method is not being called by module B. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if module B not have dependency to module A you can not call any method or class as B module. because B not have any access to A. when you compile your code from module B, not have any jar file from module A in artifact.

if you need call method but don't have access from dependency, please review your design.